# How to push data into array as a JSON tree in react native?

Tags: arrays, json, tree, push

I'm developing a mobile app using React Native. I need to put some data into an array with categories (SubKeys / Children). I have data stored in Firebase Real-time Database. So, I want to push those data into an array as that JSON tree exists. For example, I want to build an array like following. There is a category named 'Fruits'. Under that, it has 'Apple', 'Strawberry', etc. Like this, for other categories as well.

```
const items = [
    {
      name: 'Fruits',
      id: 0,
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Apple',
          id: 10,
        },
        {
          name: 'Strawberry',
          id: 17,
        },
        {
          name: 'Pineapple',
          id: 13,
        },
        {
          name: 'Banana',
          id: 14,
        },
        {
          name: 'Watermelon',
          id: 15,
        },
        {
          name: 'Kiwi fruit',
          id: 16,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Gems',
      id: 1,
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Quartz',
          id: 20,
        },
        {
          name: 'Zircon',
          id: 21,
        },
        {
          name: 'Sapphire',
          id: 22,
        },
        {
          name: 'Topaz',
          id: 23,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Plants',
      id: 2,
      children: [
        {
          name: "Mother In Law's Tongue",
          id: 30,
        },
        {
          name: 'Yucca',
          id: 31,
        },
        {
          name: 'Monsteria',
          id: 32,
        },
        {
          name: 'Palm',
          id: 33,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Provide exact input and output how you want

Comment: The output is the above array. Input is those data. First, I have an empty array. Then, I want to push the data into the array. Not as an ordinary array, but as an array with categories. As shown above. So, I want to know how to push data like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

let's consider input having value as we expect:

```
let output=[]
for(let i=0;i<input.length;i++){
  let obj={};
  obj.name = input[i].name
  obj.id = input[i].id
  obj.children = [ ...input.children]
  output.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I know that I should pass another array to this obj.children?

Comment: Pass an array having objects that contains name and id

Comment: Got it and clear. Thank you very much for your help.      :-)